# Is there any standard tool for checking hardware and drivers?

Tags: installation, 12.10, drivers

I have installed Ubuntu 12.1- on my Dell Inspiron 15r 3rd gen Laptop.
It has ATI Radeon 7670m graphics card.
How do I install drivers for all my hardware safely?
Currently gesture of trackpad, fan speed, etc are not working properly.
How do I test whether all my hardware is properly working?
Is there any standard tool for error checking, benchmarking, etc for checking hardware?
Thank You.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

*How do I test whether all my hardware is properly working? Is there any standard tool for error checking, benchmarking, etc for checking hardware?*

In Ubuntu we have such option with an application named as System testing. You can open it from unity dash by typing as System Testing.

[image: System Testing Opening]

After opening here , you can perform all your required tests. Its having everything you need.

[image: Testing Image]

Update : if you haven't found it already installed in your Ubuntu , you can install it with

```
sudo apt-get install checkbox
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: thanks.
But that does not contain test for GPU, HDD, fan, etc.

Comment: That doesn't come with Ubuntu Studio 16.04.  What is the name of the package?

Comment: @JamesBowery I have updated my answer.

Answer (score 2):

> How do I install drivers for all my hardware safely?

Basically you should not have to. Ubuntu uses generic drivers so it will have them installed already -but- sometimes you need to tweak them or block a specific module to have it working. I would suggest trying to find all the specifics for all the different hardware and have a look if others had trouble with that hardware (sometimes the hardware is MicroSoft only though this happens less and less).

If you come up short make a question on AU for each hardware part (but make sure to search first ;) )

> How do I test whether all my hardware is properly working?

Open `dash` and start typing `friendly`. This will get you to a tool that tests your system.

[image]

[More information can be found here](https://friendly.ubuntu.com/participate/) (there is a video there and a run through of the program it starts).

At the end, if you ran all the test, it can  upload the results to the Friendly site so others can see what works.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have high enough reputation to add this as a comment so:
For Ubuntu 16.04, when you search for "System Testing", the application is called "Checkbox", but does as explained above. It should be pre-installed in the system.

Comment: 'ave an upvote because this is still a valid answer.