# How to check hardware drivers in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: drivers, 18.04, gpu-driver, checkbox

Most of the answer I found about this question are out of date so I was wondering is there is a new way to check it on `Ubuntu 18.04 LTS` ?

I tried most of the solution given here: [Is there any standard tool for checking hardware and drivers?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/281714/is-there-any-standard-tool-for-checking-hardware-and-drivers/281717#281717)

Including typing:

```
sudo apt-get install checkbox
```

But then I have the following error:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package checkbox is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source
However the following packages replace it:
  checkbox-ng

E: Package 'checkbox' has no installation candidate
```

And none seems to works, so do you have any ideas if there is a tool for Ubuntu 18.04 in order to automatically check the drivers ?

Comment: **$ sudo apt-get install checkbox-ng** works. I just installed it. After that give command: `$ checkbox`

Comment: Did you try @Ced? What was the result? Kindly reply!

Comment: Hello @Marmayogi , yes sorry so it worked, now it is installed but I don't know how to use it

Comment: Did you try `$ checkbox --help` on command line?

Comment: Yes but I don't know which argument to use with `checkbox`

Comment: Try this command ` $ checkbox  check-config`

Comment: I did it but I just have as output: `No validation problems found` so it does not really help me

Comment: Go through [ubuntu man](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/checkbox.1.html) which has wealth of information and whatever you look for in this regard is available there. The ball is in your court!

Comment: Alright, thank you a lot for your help ! :)

Comment: One final word @Ced. `Checkbox`  is a hardware testing tool useful for certifying laptops, desktops and servers  with Ubuntu. A new version of Checkbox is available that is built directly on top of PlainBox. If you look something else from this command, then it may not be available.